# error 2059 with getgaborkernel() in openCV2.3.1 on visual studio C++ 2010 express

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, neural-network

```
void IPyraNet2DSourceLayer<OutType>::preprocessImage(const cv::Mat& src, cv::Mat& dest)
{   

    // initialize the gabor filter (just once)
    if (gaborKernel.cols == 0 || gaborKernel.rows == 0) 
    {   
       cv::Mat unflippedKernel = cv::getGaborKernel(
                     cv::Size(gaborKernelSize,gaborKernelSize),
                     gaborSigma, gaborTheta,
                     gaborLambda, gaborGamma, 0.0, /*psi*/);

        // flip the kernel both orizontally and vertically (as required by cv::flip2D)
        cv::flip(unflippedKernel, gaborKernel, -1);

        // the generated values are very small. Scale them.
        gaborKernel /= 2.0 * cv::sum(gaborKernel).val[0];
     }     
     // apply Histogram Equalization
     cv::equalizeHist(src, dest); 
     // convert the image from 0-255 to [-1.0 +1.0] and apply the gabor filter
     cv::Mat scaledTo1;
     dest.convertTo(scaledTo1, CV_64F, 2.0 / 255.0, -1.0); // (maxVal - minVal) / 255.0, minVal);

     if (gaborEnabled) {
         cv::Mat gaboredData;
         cv::filter2D(scaledTo1, dest, CV_64F, gaborKernel);
     } else {
         dest = scaledTo1;
     }
}
```

When i compile it, it give me the below errors, Can any body help in removing these, will be thankful

\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(200): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(196) : while compiling class template member function 'void IPyraNet2DSourceLayer::preprocessImage(const cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &)'
     with
      [
         OutType=float
      ]

\source\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(224) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IPyraNet2DSourceLayer' being compiled
    with
      [
         OutType=float
      ]

\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(200): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(196) : while compiling class template member function 'void IPyraNet2DSourceLayer::preprocessImage(const cv::Mat &,cv::Mat &)
    with
      [
         OutType=double
      ]

\ipyranet2dsourcelayer.cxx(225) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IPyraNet2DSourceLayer' being compile
       with
       [
           OutType=double
        ]

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you commented out psi, but forgot to remove the comma !

```
   cv::Mat unflippedKernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(gaborKernelSize,gaborKernelSize) , gaborSigma, gaborTheta, gaborLambda, gaborGamma, 0.0, /*psi*/);  // the comma has to go, too !
```

btw, the error only showed after *formatting* the code correctly, so learn to love the "{}" button !

Comment: @berak  would you please take a look at my question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218236/cluster-texture-based-on-features-extracted-from-gabor