# Cluster texture based on features extracted from Gabor

Tags: opencv, textures, k-means, pca, gabor-filter

I'm trying to cluster textures, based on the features extracted from Gabor bank that I've created. But the result is far from what is typically expected so here is what I'm doing >>

1-generate a filter bank (based on the Miki's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781502/how-to-get-the-real-and-imaginary-parts-of-a-gabor-kernel-matrix-in-opencv) I'm getting both real and imaginary part so that I can later extract Magnitude feature)

```
void Gabor::generateFilterbank(int bankRows,int bankCols)
{
    bankCol=bankCols;
    bankRow=bankRows;
    setBankSize();

    int thetaStep=pos_th_max/bankCols;
    int lambadaStep=(pos_lm_max/bankRows) /10;

    for (int i = 1; i <= bankRows; i++)    // cols = theta  rows = lambda
        for (int j = 1; j <= bankCols; j++ )
        {
            int ks=(kernel_size-1)/2;
            Size KernalSize(ks,ks);
            double Sigma = pos_sigma;
            double Lambda = 0.5+(i*lambadaStep);
            double Theta = (j*thetaStep)*CV_PI/180;
            double psi = pos_psi;//*CV_PI/180
            double Gamma = 0;
            vector<Mat> realImag;
            realImag.push_back(getGaborKernel(KernalSize,Sigma,Theta,Lambda,Gamma,psi,CV_32F));//real
            realImag.push_back(getGaborKernelImag(KernalSize,Sigma,Theta,Lambda,Gamma,psi,CV_32F));//imag
            Kernels.push_back(realImag);
         }

}
```

2-process input image

```
void Gabor::process(Mat img)
{
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32F, 1.0/255, 0);
    for (int i=0;(unsigned)i<Kernels.size();i++)
    {
        vector<Mat > responseIR;
        for (int j=0;(unsigned)j<Kernels[i].size();j++)
        {
            Mat IR ;
            filter2D(img, IR , CV_32F,Kernels[i][j]);
            responseIR.push_back(IR );
            IR.release();
        }
        responses.push_back(responseIR);
    }
}
```

3- extract the feature vector from all Gabor responses

```
    vector<float> Gabor::getGaborFetures(ofstream &out,float name)
    {
        vector<float>fetures;
        Mat magnituder (responses.size(),responses[0][0].rows*responses[0][0].cols,CV_32FC1, Scalar(0.0));
        fetures.push_back(name);
        if (responses.size()>0)
        {
            for (int i=0;(unsigned)i<responses.size();i+=2)
            {
                vector<float> mag,rel,imag;
    
                mat2Vector(responses[i][0],rel);
                mat2Vector( responses[i][1],imag);
                cv::magnitude(rel,imag, mag);
    
                for (int j=0;j<mag.size();j++)
                {
                  magnituder.at<float>(i,j)  =mag[j];
                }
            }
    
            PCA pca( magnituder,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,10);
            Mat result(pca.project( magnituder));
            magnituder.release();
            for (int i=0;i<result.rows;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<result.cols;j++)
                {
                    fetures.push_back(result.at<float>(i,j));
    
                }
            }
            result.release();
            for (int i=0;(unsigned)i<fetures.size();i++)
                out <<fetures[i]<<",";
            out<<endl;
            return fetures;
        }

    else
    {
        cerr<<"You have to process your image first!"<<endl;
        return fetures;
    }
}
```

4- finally cluster extracted features with K-means

```
int kt=14;
Mat labTexture;
kmeans(ftTexture,kt,labTexture,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000,0.0001),10,KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS );
```

currently, I'm testing the code on [this dataset](http://sipi.usc.edu/database/database.php?volume=textures) I expected to cluster data set to 14 class, for example, all bricks images goes to one folder.

Comment: no one has any opinion ?!

Comment: :|  92 people saw this and no one has any opinion ?!

Comment: Your question is not properly asked. Instead of showing all these lines of codes, pinpoint the most useful core lines to display, clearly explain the different steps, and show some results: how bad is your classification to what you expected? Could you quantify?

Comment: @Léonard thanks for your replay, actually the reason why I'm showing all these codes is that  I'm not sure about the procedure, the result is as follow>> all the images split into 4 categories instead of 14 categories and there is no logical pattern why these images go to each group :|